# Possible To Print 4-Up From Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, printing, add-in

I got nowhere Googling for this question so if this is a "Google Is Your Friend (GIYF)" question, I apologize in advance.

I always print source code duplex to save paper.  Is there an add-in for VS (2003) which allows you to print two pages on one side of the paper so I can print 4 pages on one sheet?  I think this is called 4-Up printing.  I'm almost certain I can do this if I drop the printing out to a file and then use an external utility but I'd like to be able to do this all from within VS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is usually a function of the printer driver.  I use it on the Canon printers to print out pamphlets and the like.

If you have the features for duplex and multipage printing, it'll be in the printer properties of the Print dialog.

To print both sides of the page (duplex), you'll need a duplex attachment on the printer or do the old even/odd page two-pass printing.

Answer (score 2):

As [spoulson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3347/spoulson) says, its a function of the printer,

1. Go File->Print
2. Click on "Properties . . ." button
3. Find an option called "Pages per
   sheet" (on my currently selected
   printer it's on the "Finishing" tab.
4. Set it to the desired number of
   pages

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

If you want more control than your printer driver provides, take a look at [FinePrint](https://fineprint.com/fp/).

It works as a virtual printer and can do all sorts of layout manipulations on print jobs. It can even combine several print jobs into one.